# Polynomial ring as a (complete) metric space

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (for example $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the $k$-algebra of polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, $n \geq 1$.

> **(1)** Does there exist a metric on $R$?

Let us consider the case $n=1$. In this case I think that we can define a metric as follows: For $A=\sum_{i=0}^{u}a_ix^i$ and $B=\sum_{i=0}^{v}b_ix^i$,
we can think of $A=(a_0,\ldots,a_u,0,\ldots)$ and $B=(b_0,\ldots,b_v,0,\ldots)$,
and define, in case $k \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$, for example:
$d(A,B)=\sum |a_i-b_i|$.

Concerning $n \geq 2$, I think that again it is a metric space. For example, if we order the monomials as follows: $1,x,y,x^2,xy,^2,x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3,\ldots$,
then each element of $k[x,y]$ can be thought of as a (finite) vector, and the distance between two elements is defined the same.

If I am not wrong, such a metric is not complete (and if we consider those metrices in $k[[x]]$/$k[[x,y]]$ etc., then they become complete).

So, if I am not wrong, I have answered my question, so I ask:

> **(2)** Does there exist a complete metric on $R$?

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: The polynomial rings $\Bbb{R}[x]$ and $\Bbb{C}[x]$ both have the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$ and hence can be made into a complete metric space by picking a bijection with $\Bbb{R}$ and using it to transfer the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$ to give an equivalent (and hence complete) metric on the polynomial ring. Did you mean to ask for a metric that make the ring operations continuous?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment; you could write it as an answer, if you like. ("Did you mean to ask for a metric that make the ring operations continuous?"= truly no, though this question sounds interesting to me).

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. I've posted the comment as an answer and will think some more about the possibility of a complete metric that makes the ring operations continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial rings $\Bbb{R}[x]$ and $\Bbb{C}[x]$ both have the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$ and hence can be made into complete metric spaces by picking a bijection with $\Bbb{R}$ and using it to transfer the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$ to give an equivalent (and hence complete) metric on the polynomial ring. The resulting metric can't be expected to have some good properties you might want: e.g. there is no reason for the algebraic operations on the polynomial rings to be continuous.

Comment: In your answer, it is possible to replace $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, right?

Comment: Yes: if $R$ is a ring with cardinality $\kappa$, then $R[x]$ has cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: @RobArthan It seems that $R[x]$ has cardinality $\max(\kappa, \aleph_0)$, for $\kappa$ may be finite.

Comment: By the way, we can proceed even easier, without using the specific cardinality of $mathbb R$: place a discrete metric on the set (in our case, on $k[x_1,x_2\dots x_n]$), which is always trivially complete.

Comment: @lisyarus, thanks for the comments.

Comment: @lisyarus: my comment should have read "with **infinite** cardinality $\kappa$". The discrete metric is certainly another possibility.